# What is best way of getting the id from edit mode into jquery function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I am calling a JavaScript function which relies on the case Id being set this case Id is being set through the edit function. Obviously I need some way of getting the case Id into jQuery function I'm thinking maybe I should parse the query string for that as you see the pattern for that is `MISObjects/Edit/5` where 5 would be the case Id?

I am using asp.net core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core. I have this code in a component view so that I can pass a different model to it.

But of course my jquery is being called before the edit action is completed their for the variables I am using becomes null

```
// GET: MISObjects/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id) {
if (id == null) {
    return NotFound();
}
        SetupViewBags();      
        var list = _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        ViewBag.Users = list;
        var mISObject = await _context.MISobject.FindAsync(id);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaseId", id.ToString());
        //Using temp data to store
        TempData["CaseId"] = id.ToString();
        SetupUploadsViewBags();    
      if (mISObject == null) {
      return NotFound();
 }
     return View(mISObject);
 }
```

But when I debug the Value is blank because the `GetAuditTrailData` gets called before the edit function has fired at least it does when I place the brake points.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<DataTableWrapper<List<MISAuditTrail>>> GetAuditTrailData() {           
        Int32.TryParse(TempData.Peek["CaseId"], out int resultCaseId);          
        var auditTrailsHistory = _context.MisAuditTrail.Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted == false && w.MISObjectId== resultCaseId).ToList();
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditTrailsHistory);
        DataTableWrapper<List<MISAuditTrail>> data = new DataTableWrapper<List<MISAuditTrail>>() {
            data = auditTrailsHistory
        };

        return data;
   }
```

**This is the jQuery which resides in my components view**

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#audTrailTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: "/MISObjects/GetAuditTrailData/"  ,
                type: "get",
                database: "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "createdDate" },
                { "data": "createdBy" },
                { "data": "action" }
            ],
            "scrollY": "200px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false // for disable multiple column at once
        })
    });
    alert(caseId);
</script>

}
```

**My View Component**

```
namespace MISSystem.Web.ViewComponents {

 [ViewComponent(Name = "AudiTrailList")]
 public class AuditTrailViewComponent : ViewComponent {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    private readonly MISDBContext db;
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public AuditTrailViewComponent(MISDBContext context , IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        db = context;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;

    }


    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
 int caseId) {
        CaseId = caseId;

        var items = await GetItemsAsync(caseId);
        
        _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaseId",CaseId.ToString());
         return View(items);
    }
    private Task<List<MISAuditTrail>> GetItemsAsync(int caseId) {
        return db.MisAuditTrail.Where(x => x.isActive ==true &&  x.MISObjectId == caseId).ToListAsync();
    }
 }
}
```

The component gets called as such which is fine when the edit mode fires it finds the id of the case but when the ajax calls thats functions its gone and is null.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("AudiTrailList", new { caseId = Model.Id })
```

Comment: Thank u for the editing who help in the grammar of the question

Comment: According to your description, I still couldn't understand your issue clearly. I found you directly alert the caseid in the  $(document).ready function. Do you mean you find this this caseid is null? If possible, please post the whole view about your current page and how you call the edit page. If you could post more details codes and description, it will be more easily for us to find out the issue.